# Error in Play on Get: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/routes : Unsupported major.minor >version

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I recently installed Java 1.6 and play 2.10.0. When attempting to run a skeleton web app on the play framework I receive this error upon a page request.

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/routes : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0]]
```

I've read the play framework threads regarding the unsupported major.minor errors and took action based on what I could understand. After downloading and installing java version 1.6 (I had been using 1.7) my environment looks like the following and I am still receiving the same error. How do I move beyond this error?

```
java  1.6.0_33

javac 1.6.0_45
```

Play 2.1.2 (Using Java 1.6.0_33 and Scala 2.10.0)

Path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Silverfrost\FTN95;C:\Program Files (x86)\Silverfrost\FTN95\FTN95 for Microsoft Visual >Studio;C:\Users\zach\nodejs;C:\Users\zach\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\zach\NodeApps;C:\Users\zach\Downloads\play-2.1.2\play-2.1.2;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;
```

The error I receive is as follows ...

### Exception...

```
2013-07-12 00:53:00,472 - [INFO] - from play in play-internal-execution-context-1 
Application started (Dev)

2013-07-12 00:53:00,781 - [ERROR] - from application in play-internal-execution-context-3 


! @6f0e5c888 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/routes : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$18$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:310) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$18$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:308) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
```

Comment: Make sure that you are using the same JDK for compiling and running your Play application.

Comment: As far as I can tell with my limited Java experience, things look to be in sync. Java version 1.6.0_33 and Play 2.1.2 using Java 1.6.0_33 (see info in original post). I do see the javac version is 1.6.0_45 but that is the javac whick came with JDK 1.6

Comment: in a terminal, try `java -version` and  `javac -version`

Comment: Observe original post.

Comment: I had created the Scala/Play project I was attempting to run under my previous install of JDK 1.7. After backing down to JDK 1.6 I never recompiled the project. Now that I backed the JDK down to 1.6 and recreated the project in that environment, everything seems to work fine now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I failed to recompile my Play/Scala app under the JDK1.6 environment which I had backed down to, from JDK 1.7. Down-versioning to JDK1.6 and blowing away / recreating my Play/Scala project in JDK 1.6 environment solved the errors.